# After Corporation terminates Consumer's contract for a false reason, what are Consumer's remedies?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [After Corporation terminates Consumer's contract for a false reason, what are Consumer's remedies?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87299/after-corporation-terminates-consumers-contract-for-a-false-reason-what-are-co)

What "details or clarity" do you need? How can I improve my post to reopen?

---

A Corporation terminated Consumer's service, and notified the Consumer in writing with a bogus reason. Consumer can disprove or gainsay this bogus reason.

##### Does Consumer have remedies to compel Corporation to reverse the termination, and reinstate Consumer's contract? What consumer protection legislation assists Consumer?

### Real life cases with Meta Platforms Inc. (formerly Facebook Inc.) that owns Instagram.

Instagram has been terminating Consumers'  accounts in Canada and the USA, falsely alleging that their IP address "has been flagged as an open proxy." See screen shot below. But backed by evidence from their Internet Service Provider, many Consumers can prove their IP address has NEVER BEEN "an open proxy".

[image]

I  cannot find the link to the court reports or news articles.  Just edit my post, if  you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What "details or clarity" do you need?

You might want provide a link to the contract and identify the clause(s) you think the corporation has breached. Usually those contracts or "Terms & Conditions" are too long for us to read in their entirety, which is why just providing a link to the T&C is not enough.

Even if someone knows beforehand the applicable legislation, the contract you signed might outline the method(s) of dispute resolution (such as mediation or arbitration) as well as other prerequisite steps to enforce any available remedies.